# istio 1.5.1 - How to add SameSite attribute to all cookies

Tags: kubernetes, cookies, istio, envoyproxy, samesite

How can I enforce and add, at the `istio` level, the `samesite` attribute (for example, `SameSite=None; Secure;`) to all cookies that do not have it?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look a [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/27006) solution with envoyfilter. Does it help to your use case?

Comment: Thanks @thomas, I tried that one solution (also its followup here: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/12970). However, it seemed that it could not be generalized to more than one cookie. In my case, I would like to have it applied to all the cookies.

Comment: Take a look at my solution [here](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/12970#issuecomment-872243474)

Comment: It's not exactly addressing your problem, but can be generalized, so you need to modify it a bit.

Comment: Thanks @pbn, I will test it as soon as possible.